# Managed Search Property not being returned in Search Results

Tags: search-results

I have a managed metadata column 'VideoArea' tied to a Search Metadata Property named 'PuroCastVideoArea'.  I am firing a full text query ( as below ). The problem is that the search service returns Metadata Property 'PuroCastVideoArea' only in the first case.  IE for the second query, the results are returned but there is no PuroCastVideoArea node/data in it. Though in both the cases, rest of the custom properties like PuroCastVideoDescription etc is returned

Note that these queries are being fired via Javascript using SPServices library

Any idea what could be done to make the second query return the column values?

Query Returning Data

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>
    <Query>
        <Context>
            <QueryText language="en-US" type="MSSQLFT">SELECT Title, Path,PuroCastVideoDescription,PuroCastThumbNail,PuroCastDuration,PuroCastVideoArea, DocId FROM Scope() WHERE "Scope" = 'Videos' AND CONTAINS(PuroCastVideoArea, 'SharePoint')
            </QueryText>
        </Context>
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Query not returning data

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>
    <Query>
        <Context>
            <QueryText language="en-US" type="MSSQLFT">SELECT TOP 12 Title, Path,PuroCastVideoDescription,PuroCastThumbNail,PuroCastDuration,PuroCastVideoArea, DocId FROM Scope() WHERE "Scope" = 'Videos'  ORDER BY "PuratosCreatedDate" DESC</QueryText>
        </Context>
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Comment: Why are you using double quotes around the Order by?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010 or 2007?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, i delete the content source and recrated it...its working now

On closer inspection ,i noticed that the query 2 also returns the property but only for very few elements  ( infact out of 50 only 1 items did return this value though , the value was filled on all the elements ).